# Http log parsing in c++

Tags: c++, http, parsing, logging

I have various requests given. Two of the requests are given as an example. And filters are given in the following format:

Filters:

1. REQUEST_TYPE: GET|POST|PUT|DELETE
2. RELATIVE_URL: /main/index or / , etc.
3. IP: 111.119.206.2 or 127.0.0.1, etc.
4. REQUEST_FORMAT: JS or JSON or HTML or null/blank, etc. (Note: null/blank request format should be treated as HTML.)
5. RESPONSE_CODE: "200 OK" or "401 Unauthorized" or "422 Unprocessable Entity", etc

Example of filter is given below request. I have to parse the requests and check for these filters and output if these filters are present in request. Output should contain 5 lines for each filter each which denotes the count of occurence of each filter in each request.

Please suggest me on how to take the input and process as i receive the input so as to finish this activity in least time.

Request Format:

```
    Started <REQUEST_TYPE> <RELATIVE_URL> for <IP> at <REQUEST_TIMESTAMP>
          Processing by <CONTROLLER>#<ACTION> as <REQUEST_FORMAT>
          Parameters: <Key Value pair for each parameters>
        <LOG_LINE_1>
        <LOG_LINE_2>
        ...
        ...
        <LOG_LINE_N>
        Rendered <SOME_TEMPLATE_0> (<TIMETAKEN_0>)
        Rendered <SOME_TEMPLATE_1> (<TIMETAKEN_1>)
        ...
        ...
        Rendered <SOME_TEMPLATE_N> (<TIMETAKEN_N>)
        Completed <RESPONSE_CODE> in <OVERALL_TIME_TAKEN> (Views: <TIME_VIEWS> | ActiveRecord: <TIME_ACTIVE_RECORD> | Sphinx: <TIME_SPHINX>)
```

Request 1:

```
    Started GET "/terminal/is_on?ts=1448979876581&b=Chrome&v=46.0&timestamp=1448979524369&sl=1421&tabOpened=1448979396.012" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Dec 01 19:54:36 +0530 2015
          Processing by TerminalController#is_on as JSON
          Parameters: {"tabOpened"=>"1448979396.012", "v"=>"46.0", "b"=>"Chrome", "ts"=>"1448979876581", "sl"=>"1421", "timestamp"=>"1448979524369"}
        [BS_SESSION_LOG 218] 3 : Tue Dec 01 19:54:37 +0530 2015 : /terminal/is_on : before request
        LIVE SESSION LOGS [Tue Dec 01 14:24:37 UTC 2015] [SummaryLog Transition] - User: 3 - Inside terminal#is_on - sl - 1421 - Session: 627632189903c04da7801aafbac4d992 - bs_session_id: 218
        UnLocking session id 627632189903c04da7801aafbac4d992, bs_session id: 627632189903c04da7801aafbac4d992
        [BS_SESSION_LOG 218] 3 : Tue Dec 01 19:54:37 +0530 2015 : /terminal/is_on : after request : true
        Completed 200 OK in 446ms (Views: 11.1ms | ActiveRecord: 14.0ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)
```

Request 2:

```
    Started GET "/status/is_new?ts=1448979876581" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Dec 01 20:01:18 +0530 2015
          Processing by TerminalController#is_on as JSON
          Parameters: {"tabOpened"=>"1448979396.012", "v"=>"46.0", "b"=>"Chrome", "ts"=>"1448980278551", "sl"=>"1421", "timestamp"=>"1448979524369"}
        [BS_SESSION_LOG 218] 3 : Tue Dec 01 20:01:19 +0530 2015 : /terminal/is_on : before request
        LIVE SESSION LOGS [Tue Dec 01 14:31:19 UTC 2015] [SummaryLog Transition] - User: 3 - Inside terminal#is_on - sl - 1421 - Session: 627632189903c04da7801aafbac4d992 - bs_session_id: 218
        UnLocking session id 627632189903c04da7801aafbac4d992, bs_session id: 627632189903c04da7801aafbac4d992
        [BS_SESSION_LOG 218] 3 : Tue Dec 01 20:01:19 +0530 2015 : /terminal/is_on : after request : true
        Completed 200 OK in 539ms (Views: 9.0ms | ActiveRecord: 22.4ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)
```

and filter is :

1. GET
2. /terminal/is_on?ts=1448979663546&b=Chrome&v=46.0&timestamp=1448979524369&sl=1421&tabOpened=1448979396.012
3. 127.0.0.1
4. JSON
5. 200 OK

Output:

```
2
1
2
2
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need first to document and fully *specify* the log *file format*. Using [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation is a convenient way to document such a format. You cannot define a file format just by giving examples (or even with some ill-defined "template" like your *Request Format:* thing; you don't explain what a `<REQUEST_FORMAT>` or a `<LOG_LINE>` really is;  you should specify a lot better the input and you should document that somewhere; e.g. what exactly is a `<REQUEST_FORMAT>`, can it contains underscores, dollar signs, digits?).

Once you have *entirely* specified the format (with all details), you can use standard [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques (probably you may need some [lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) first). Probably some simple [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) is enough (and coding that is simple once you have *specified the input [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_%28programming_languages%29)*). Otherwise, read the first half of the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools#Second_edition) to learn more about parsing. Or consider using some [parser generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler) like [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/) or [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) + [flex](https://www.gnu.org/software/flex/).

You might look into existing web server log file formats, e.g. [here](https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/apache-logging-basics/).

You may use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Perhaps writing some [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) script might be enough for your parsing needs.

Comment: Then use standard parsing techniques. But I don't feel that your explanation is really specifying the request format. You should (at least on paper) write some EBNF. Once you have completed the specification of the format, writing a parser is standard practice.

Comment: i just need to write a simple implementation in c++. The things u told might take some time.

Comment: But they are necessary for the task. Once you understood the basic concepts and have specified *completely* the syntax, coding the parser is quite simple.